# Argument - simple prolog

Tags: prolog

Want to expand the argument `q(M,N):-` that should evaluate true , only if 
we can express `M` as sum of two numbers , that also these same two numbers would give the the product of `N`. Meaning something like `A+B=M` and `A*B=N` (`M,N>0` both Integers)

So I've tried something like :

```
sum(A,B,M) :- M is A+B.

prod(A,B,N) :- N is A*B.

q(M,N) :- sum(A,B,M),
          prod(A,B,N).
```

But yeah not a great plan.

some expected outcomes should be:

```
| ?- q(18,45).
yes
| ?- q(45,18).
no
| ?- q(4,4).
yes
| ?- q(5,5).
no
| ?- q(16,64).
yes
| ?- q(12,25).
no
| ?- q(25,24).
yes
| ?- q(36,120).
no
| ?- q(100,2499).
yes
| ?- q(100,267).
no
| ?- q(653,98770).
yes
| ?- q(653,98880).
no
```

Comment: You should apecify the range of A and B. You can use clpfd library to do this

Comment: both A and B Integers >0 yes , from the test questions in the end you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **very** basic solution for your problem, using `between/3` from swi prolog, without heavilly modifing your program is:

```
sum(A,B,M) :- M is A+B.

prod(A,B,N) :- N is A*B.

q(M,N) :- 
    between(0,1000,A),
    between(0,1000,B),
    sum(A,B,M),
    prod(A,B,N).
```

In this case, all numbers between `0` and `1000` are considered for `A` and `B`. However, there are some weakness. For instance, values for `A` and `B` can be exchanged (`q(18,45)` succeeds for `A = 3` and `B = 15` and `A = 15` and `B = 3`). To remove this redundancy you can impose `B < A`. To further improve the algorithm, you can set a range for A and B based on the value of the sum and the product. Certainly both `A` and `B` must be less than the value `M` in your code. Like:

```
q(M,N) :- 
    between(0,M,A),
    between(0,A,B),
    M is A+B,
    N is A*B.
```

You can add further constraints to improve the performances, for instance considering cases where the product is 0 etc...

You can use also [clpfd library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) to solve this problem.